# C++11 random numbers

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I need to generate random numbers, but from as wide a range as possible (64 bit at least). I don't care if the distribution is perfect, so `std::rand()` would work, but it only returns an `int`. I understand that c++11 has some random number generating capability that can give any size number, but is very complex to use. Can someone post a simple example of how to use it as simply as possible to get the described functionality (64 bit or more random numbers) in as simple a way as possible (like `std::rand()`)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is how to use the C++11 random number generation for this purpose (adjusted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  /* Initialise. Do this once (not for every
     random number). */
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());

  /* This is where you define the number generator for unsigned long long: */
  std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> dis;

  /* A few random numbers: */    
  for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Instead of `unsigned long long`, you could use `std::uintmax_t` from `cstdint` to get the largest possible integer range (without using an actual big-integer library).

Comment: This is plenty good for nearly all use, but note that it only gives `sizeof(unsigned)` bytes of entropy for the seed. If you need more, it's possible to pass a [`std::seed_seq`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) into `mt19937`'s constructor in order to pass as many random bytes as you want.

Comment: Assuming that you just wanted a 64bit u_long, which is the same type as the output of `mt19937_64`, is there any reason to use `uniform_int_distribution` in that case?

Comment: @HammeIAm No, I think it's possible to go without `uniform_int_distribution` then, because the Mersenne Twister strives to produce a uniform distribution anyway.

Answer (score 15):

We could easily wrap a random number generator engine into srand/rand-like methods like this:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

struct MT19937 {
private:
    static std::mt19937_64 rng;
public:
    // This is equivalent to srand().
    static void seed(uint64_t new_seed = std::mt19937_64::default_seed) {
        rng.seed(new_seed);
    }

    // This is equivalent to rand().
    static uint64_t get() {
        return rng();
    }
};

std::mt19937_64 MT19937::rng;


int main() {
    MT19937::seed(/*put your seed here*/);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        std::cout << MT19937::get() << std::endl;
}
```

(Like `srand` and `rand`, this implementation does not care about thread-safety.)

Well the wrapper functions are so trivial that you could just use the engine directly.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

static std::mt19937_64 rng;

int main() {
    rng.seed(/*put your seed here*/);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i)
        std::cout << rng() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::mt19937_64::default_seed` is standardized as `5489u`, so your sample programs will always produce the same output sequence.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin: Yes. Just like in the `srand()`, you need to provide your own seed to get a distinct random sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Not C++11, but easy enough

`((unsigned long long)rand() << 32) + rand()` Here we generate two parts of int64 as int32's

As `JasonD` pointed out, it assumes that `rand()` generate 32bit integer. It' spossible to xor
`rand() << x`, `rand() << (2*x)`, `rand() << (3*x)`, etc, where `x` <= bit's in generate by `rand()` number`. It should be OK too.

Comment: Assumes that rand() actually returns a 32-bit number. It's likely only 31-bit, if it's not 15-bit.

Comment: @JasonD Yes, @RiaD should check `RAND_MAX` to determine this.

Comment: Under Microsoft cl, up to the current 19.x, `RAND_MAX` is 0x7FFF, or 15 bit.