# rand() is not changing values when run again in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am making a function to make different random value when I run the executable file again. This is my function to make a bit 0 and 1. The first time, I run it and get output is 0 1 1 1. And I run the .exe  the output is same with prior time. What is happening? I want different output when I run again. Can you help me?

```
int randBit()
{
    int bit;
    double randval;
    randval = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    if(randval<0.5) bit=0;
    else bit=1;
    return bit;
}
```

Comment: Use `srand(time(NULL))` before `rand()`

Comment: @AlterMann: looks like an answer to me...

Comment: If you are using C++11, another choice is [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009637/c11-random-numbers).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `<random>` header.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist (0,1);
int random_number = dist(mt);
```

Call `dist(mt)` every time you need a new random number.

Answer (score 2):

You need `srand` function in main.

seed it with time:

```
  #include <time.h> //header for time

  int main(){
       srand(time(NULL)); // call only once and preferably at the start of main 

       // your code including the function randBit()

       return 0;
 }
```

---

**Here is a sample code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randBit()
{
   int bit;
   double randval;
   randval = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
   if(randval<0.5) bit=0;
   else bit=1;
   return bit;
}

int main(){

      srand(time(NULL));
      int i=0,random=0;

      for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            random = randBit();
            printf("%d ",random);
      }

      printf("\n");  
      return 0;
}
```

**And this is the output:**

Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ ./test

1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `srand()` prior to `rand()` first call. For Windows you can use:

```
srand( GetTickCount() );
```

And platform-independant variant:

```
srand( time(NULL) );
```

Comment: It's only needed one time. Not every time before rand() is called.

Comment: What is library of GetTickCount(). I am using Visual studio 2010

Comment: @user2938494 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user2938494 see my answer  ... use a standard function like time . rather than OS specific function like GetTickCount

Answer (score 0):

From the manpage:

> The  rand()  function returns a **pseudo-random** integer in the range 0
>   to RAND_MAX inclusive.

This means that `rand` does not actually generate random values on each call, but takes a seed as an initial value and generates pseudo random values based on that seed. With a specific seed, each sequence of calls to `rand()` will provide the same sequence of "random" numbers.

The seed can be initialized with the `srand()` function, and a good approach to having a different sequence of produced numbers in each execution is to use `time(NULL)` as the seed.

Please note that you need to initialize the seed **only once**, so you may decide to do this in the `main` function of your program.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The `rand()` function in C is *pseudo random* and thus it needs a *seed*. This seed can be any number but is usually the current time, sensor data or anything else that is less *predictable*.

The seed has a *default value* which result in the same sequence of "random" numbers each time you run the program. To set the seed you can use the `srand()` function, for example `srand(time(NULL))` to use the current time as seed. The random value is caluculated from the seed and thus `rand()` caluculates a new one on each call based on the previous.