# How to use boost::uuids::uuid to convert to 128/64 bit numbers?

Tags: c++, boost, std, uuid, 128-bit

I use this code to produce UUIDs from boost:

```
boost::uuids::random_generator gen;
boost::uuids::uuid uuidId = gen();
string randomUUID = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(uuidId);
std::remove( randomUUID.begin(), randomUUID.end(), '-');
randomUUID = "0x" + randomUUID;
```

It gives me hex numbers like: "0xCC5B9F6946EF4448A89EDB2042E0B084".

**My question is: how convert this string (128 bit hex number) into 128 long long OR 64 bit long long (it it Ok to loose higher data)?**

Standard C atoll and C++ std::stoll dont help in this case.

UUID prefered for random generation quality.

Thank you!

Comment: Using UUIDs to generate random numbers is an awful idea. They've not got the entropy of a similar, properly generated random number using something like a mersenne twister. Do yourself a favour and actually use the functionality built into c++ standard library to generate random numbers [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14009667/2331956). Also taking substrings of UUIDs is a [plain bad idea](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823/)

Comment: I have Mersener Twister and in my case it looks like this:

Comment: I have Mersener Twister and in my case it looks like this:    auto const seed = std::random_device()();
    std::mt19937 mt(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(12345678, 99999999);
    long l1;
    long l2;
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        l1 = dist(mt);
        l2 = dist(mt);
        std::cout << l1 << l2 << "\n";
    }
I think that UUID can provide more quality random numbers.

Comment: boost::uuids::random_generator *uses* Mersenne Twister. So there is no reason to expect it to provide better quality random generation than using Mersenne Twister directly. And, as Mike says, using a substring of a UUID to generate a random number seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a random 64bit unsigned integer then you can just use standard C++11:

```
std::mt19937_64 engine(std::random_device{}());
std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> distribution;
auto ui64 = distribution(engine);
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hG4JmoI5yYpJ9MGF).

Comment: And exceptions ?!

Answer (score 0):

It works this way but the entropy needs research:

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;
//...
ull ui64 = 0;
const int startPosition = 18;//can vary - we can use rand() too
const int lengthHex = 14;//can vary - we can use rand() too
boost::uuids::random_generator gen;
boost::uuids::uuid uuidId = gen();
string randomUUID = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(uuidId);
std::remove( randomUUID.begin(), randomUUID.end(), '-');
randomUUID = "0x" + randomUUID.substr(startPosition, lengthHex);
ui64 = std::stoull(randomUUID, 0, 16); //random out of UUID
std::cout << ui64 << '\n';
```