# How would I print a random array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I'm trying to print a random element, to create a random guessing game, but i dont know how i would call a random element. How would i make a random number that the array would take and output the element assigned to that number?

Comment: Searching the Internet for "c++ random int" would probably yield the result immediately.

Comment: Do you know how to get a specific element from an array based on an index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++11 random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009637/c11-random-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate a random integer between 0 and (the array size - 1), both inclusive.
2. Access your array with an index equal to this random number.

We can't give you ready-to-use code unless you show some efforts in terms of your own code.

Comment: I didn't realise you could put an integer as the array number

Comment: @Amadeus: what would be the use of arrays if you couldn't?