# C++ Placing Random Values In A Multiplication Chart (Nested Loop)

Tags: c++

I created a multiplication table for the integers 1...10. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
      std::cout << "\t" << i * j;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And my output is this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30
4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50
6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60
7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70
8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80
9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

The problem I am struggling with is that I need to insert a random number that represents an error value inside the multiplication table. For example:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20
3   6   9   13  15  18  21  24  27  30
```

As you can see in this example, the error value is 13 where 3 x 4 = 12, but instead there is the number 13.

Should I use another loop to insert the random number? If so, how to go about it?

Comment: Based on which condition should the error be inserted?

Comment: Your explanation /motive is very vague, I cant figure out what you are trying to do. 
Its better to provide what you have done, and what exactly you need to achieve so we can help

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detailed information to the objective of my program. This multiplication table chart is already required to have an error value because the program will prompt the user to specify the location of the value error by asking the row number and column number. If the user enter's the wrong information, the program will prompt the correct location of the row and column. If right, a congratulations will be displayed. This is meant to enhance my understand of using nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<random>` header file for this.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
// it produces uniformly distributed random integers in the range [a, b] (both inclusive)
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1); // either add 0 or 1 (1 will be the error -- can change a,b according to your need)

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
  {
    std::cout << "\t" << i * j + dis(gen); // just add the error value to your multiplication
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream> // input/output
#include <random>

struct FieldData {
    using Row = unsigned int;
    using Col = unsigned int;

    const Row rows{10};
    const Col cols{10};    

    Row err_row;
    Col err_col;

    unsigned int err_value;

    FieldData() {} // use default values for rows/cols
    FieldData(Row max_row, Col max_col) : rows(std::move(max_row)), cols(std::move(max_col)) {} // use given values for rows/cols
};

void print_field(const FieldData& data)
{
    for (FieldData::Row row=1;row <= data.rows; row++)
    {
        for (FieldData::Col col = 1; col <= data.cols; col++)
        {
            if (row == data.err_row && col == data.err_col)
                std::cout << "\t" << data.err_value;
            else
                std::cout << "\t" << row*col;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

FieldData get_field(std::mt19937& generator)
{
    FieldData data;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<FieldData::Row> dist_rows(1, data.rows); // random for row
    std::uniform_int_distribution<FieldData::Row> dist_cols(1, data.cols); // random for col
    std::uniform_int_distribution<FieldData::Row> dist_result(1, data.rows*data.cols); // random for result


    data.err_row = dist_rows(generator);
    data.err_col = dist_cols(generator);

    data.err_value = dist_result(generator);

    if (data.err_value != data.err_row*data.err_col)
        data.err_value--; // avoid correct value on error pos

    return data;
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());

    while (true)
    {
        auto field = get_field(generator);
        print_field(field);


        // some code to ask the user and so on.... (std::cin ...)


        std::cout << "Error value '" << field.err_value << "' is on row " << field.err_row << ", col " << field.err_col << std::endl;

        // if (... some code to check if user wants to break...)
        break;

        // code to go on
        // go on
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As requested by the questioner, a version without further constructs:

```
#include <iostream> // input/output
#include <random>

int main()
{
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 generator(rd());

   unsigned int rows = 10;
   unsigned int cols = 10;
   std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist_rows(1, rows); // random for row (1 to value of field_rows)
   std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist_cols(1, cols); // random for col (1 to value of field_cols)
   std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist_result(1, rows * cols); // random for result

   while (true) // infinite loop - must be interrupted explicitly with break or similar
   {    
      unsigned int err_row = dist_rows(generator);     // Generate the random number that defines the row
      unsigned int err_col = dist_cols(generator);     // Generate the random number that defines the col
      unsigned int err_value = dist_result(generator); // Generate the random value

      if (err_value != err_row * err_col)
         err_value--; // avoid correct value on error position - simple decrement the value

      // print_field
      for (unsigned int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
      {
         for (unsigned int col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
         {
            if (row == err_row && col == err_col) // condition to insert the error value
               std::cout << "\t" << err_value;
            else
               std::cout << "\t" << row * col;
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }

      //
      // some code to ask the user and so on.... (std::cin ...)
      //

      std::cout << "Error value '" << err_value << "' is on row " << err_row << ", col " << err_col << std::endl;

      // if (... some code to check if user wants to break...)
      break;

      // code to go on
      // go on
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I hope this answer helps you, I have separated the different parts a little bit to make it more clearly arranged for you. The code should at least give you a rough idea how something like this could be implemented. Depending on the use case, a separate class or something similar would of course be appropriate.
The code in the second variant differs from the functionality only in that the uniform_int_distributions are outside the while(true) scope and thus are not always "rebuilt" as is the case in the first variant (since more dynamic and modularity would have been possible in principle).

Comment: The `(row == 4 && col == 3)` lets the program specifically assigns some random values always at 3x4 position and nowhere else which is contradictory of what OP asked.

Comment: I've asked on which condition the position should be based... maybe i missunderstood?!

Comment: This multiplication table chart from the start must have an error value because the program will prompt the user to specify the location of the value error by asking the row number and column number. If the user enter's the wrong information, the program will prompt the correct location of the row and column. If right, a congratulations will be displayed. This program will be in a do-while loop - asking the user if he or she would like to play again. Thus, it is critical for the location of the random number to be in a different spot each time.

Comment: I do have to state that I am new and have no idea what random header file and it's functions are. I am using Starting Out W/ C++ 9th by Tony Gladis. I have yet to come across std::random_device, auto, uniform_int_distrubution, etc.

Comment: @Wolfgang Your code provides exactly what I am looking for! It's on point! The only thing is I have no idea what you wrote. I have not gone into structures yet, I barely started to learn about classes. I have not heard or read about the terms using, auto, random_device rd, mt199937 generator, etc. Is there a way to produce the same results that your code produces but in a way that only incorporates loops, if/else it, else, and maybe just classes? I am new to C++ and my brain is trying to understand what you wrote. Could you perhaps give me a link that would best teach me this information?

Comment: @AndyBautista, the idea was to give you a rough idea how such a condition can be checked and considered within the nested loop. The structuring of the code was simply to make it more clear for you. I will add to the example - but I can only strongly recommend to deal with structs etc. as structuring code is very, very important.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use another loop to insert the random number? If so, how to go about it?

You're only inserting one error, so it doesn't make much sense to a loop for that.

Well, why don't you first decide where the random number goes? Once you know that, you can modify the inner loop body, as follows:

```
int value = i * j;
if ((i == error_location.row) and (j = error_location.column)) {
    value = // code for introducing an error, e.g. sample a random answer,
            // or a random offset added to the correct answer etc.
}
std::cout << "\t" << i * j;
```

The decision of a position for the erroneous values can be made using the C++  header, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14009637/1593077). In your case it would be something like the following:

```
constexpr const int table_leg { 10 };
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> coordinate_distribution(0, table_leg - 1);
struct { int row, col; } error_location = 
    { coordinate_distribution(gen), coordinate_distribution(gen) };
```

Notes:

- I suggest replacing `i` with `row` or `row_index` and `j` with `col` or `column` or `column_index`; also, using the named constant instead of repeating the "magic number" `10`.
- I've assumed you don't want to store your multiplication table in a buffer, then replace one value in there with an error. If you *are* storing the table somewhere, you could avoid the complicated inner loop and just set the error after filling in all the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

So thank's to everyone's input - especially @Wolfgang.
I did read up on C++11's random header file and it's functions.
I did create a source code with random functions and one without. 
Any feed would be appreciated on how to make my source code more efficient. 
Other than that, it achieves what I needed it to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

const unsigned int ROWS = 10;
const unsigned int COLUMNS = 10;

void randomValue(unsigned int &, unsigned int &, unsigned int &);

int main() 
{   
  unsigned int rValue;
  unsigned int cValue;
  unsigned int pValue;

  unsigned int rowError; 
  unsigned int columnError;
  unsigned int productError;

  unsigned int userRowGuess;
  unsigned int userColumnGuess;

  char choice;  

  do 
  { 
    randomValue(rValue, cValue, pValue); 

    std::cout << "\033[2J\033[0;0H"; // This code clears the screen 
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;       
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << "++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << "+ Multiplication Table +" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(35) << "++++++++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;   

    while (true)
    { 
      rowError = rValue;
      columnError = cValue;
      productError = pValue;

      if (productError == rowError * columnError)
      {
        productError--;
      }

      for (unsigned int row = 1; row <= ROWS; row++)
      {
        for (unsigned int column = 1; column <= COLUMNS; column++)
        {
          if (row == rowError && column == columnError)
          { 
            std::cout << "\t" << "" << productError;       
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << "\t" <<  row * column;
          }
        }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      }  
      break;
    }


    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "Type in the column number " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "of the location of the    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "error & then press        " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "[Enter]: ";
    std::cin >> userColumnGuess;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\t\t" << "Type in the row number " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "of the location of the    " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "error & then press        " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "[Enter]: ";
    std::cin >> userRowGuess;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    if (userRowGuess != rowError && userColumnGuess != columnError)
    {
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "Your answer was incorrect!" << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "Error value '" << productError << "' is located" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "on row " << rowError << ", column " << columnError << "." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "You are correct! You win!" << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "Would you like to play again?" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "Type in 'Y' for yes or 'N'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t\t" << "for no & then press [Enter]: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    while (choice != 'y' && choice != 'Y' && choice != 'n' && choice != 'N')
    {
      std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "Invalid entry. Only 'Y' or 'N'" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "are accepted answers." << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "Would you like to play again?" << std::endl << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "Type in 'Y' for yes or 'N' for" << std::endl;
      std::cout << "\t\t" << "no & then press [Enter]: ";
      std::cin >> choice;
    }   
    std::cout << std::endl;

  } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'); 

  std::cout << "\t\t" << "Press [Enter] to continue....." << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  std::cin.get();

  return 0;
}

void randomValue(unsigned int &rValue, unsigned int &cValue, unsigned int &pValue)
{ 
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

  unsigned int r = rValue = (rand() % ROWS) + 1;
  unsigned int c = cValue = (rand() % COLUMNS) + 1;
  unsigned int p = pValue = (rand() % (ROWS * COLUMNS)) + 1;
}
```