# Number generator is not functioning properly in my C++ dice game program

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ as I am trying to learn from my mistakes. I am writing a program that is supposed to make each player throws a dice, and the one with the largest number gets to start a game by throwing the dice twice. If the dice throw value for both is equal. Then, they throw again until someone gets the largest value. If the player, who started, gets 3-3, 5-5, 6-6, 6-5, the player wins, and if the player gets 1-1, 2-2, 4-4, 1-2, the player loses. If neither, the player who started has his turn finished, and then the second player starts. If he fails to satisfy the same conditions; either losing or winning, then the game is a draw. I have tried to implement that, but it does not work and I do not know why. I am assuming that the random number generator did not work properly. This is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout << " -- Barbooth dice-rolling game with 2 players –" << endl;
    cout << endl;
   
    int numOne = 1;
    int numTwo = 2;
    int numThree = 3;
    int numFour = 4;
    int numFive = 5;
    int numSix = 6;
    int firstThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int secondThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int p1 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player one
    int p2 = (rand() % 6) + 1; //First throw for player two
    int p1s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player one
    int p2s = (rand() % 6) + 1; //Second throw for player two
    int thirdThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int fourthThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int thirdThrows = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int fourthThrows = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int fivthThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int sixthThrow = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
    int fivthThrow1 = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    int sixthThrow1 = (rand() % 6) + 1; 
   
    cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 1: " << firstThrow << endl;
    cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
    cout << "Player 2: " << secondThrow << endl;
    cout << endl;
   
    if(firstThrow > secondThrow)
    {
        cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 1: " << p1 << endl;
        cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 1: " << p1s << endl;
    }
    else if(firstThrow < secondThrow)
    {
        cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 2: " << p2 << endl;
        cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 2: " << p2s << endl;
    }
    else if(firstThrow == secondThrow)
    {
        cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 1: " << thirdThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
        cout << "Player 2: " << fourthThrow << endl;
        
        if(thirdThrow > fourthThrow)
        {
            cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << endl;
            cout << "Player 1, please enter to roll." << endl;
            cout << "Player 1: " << sixthThrow1 << endl;
            
        }
        else if(fourthThrow > thirdThrow)
        {
            cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << endl;
            cout << "Player 2, please enter to roll." << endl;
            cout << "Player 2: " << sixthThrow << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Tie!" << endl;
    }
    
    // All game conditions
    if(p1 == numThree && p1s == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";
        
      }
     else if(p1 == numFive && p1s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n"; 
        
      }
     else if(p1 == numSix && p1s == numSix)
      {
         cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";
        
      }
     else if(p1 == numSix && p1s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(p1 == numOne && p1s == numOne)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numTwo && p1s == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numFour && p1s == numFour)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p1 == numOne && p1s == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << p1 << "-" << p1s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numThree && p2s == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numFive && p2s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numSix && p2s == numSix)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numSix && p2s == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
      else if(p2 == numOne && p2s == numOne)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numTwo && p2s == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numFour && p2s == numFour)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(p2 == numOne && p2s == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << p2 << "-" << p2s << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
      
      ////////////////////////////////////
      else if(fivthThrow1 == numThree && sixthThrow1 == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numFive && sixthThrow1 == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numSix && sixthThrow1 == numSix)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numSix && sixthThrow1 == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout<< "Player 1 wins\n";  
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numOne && sixthThrow1 == numOne)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numTwo && sixthThrow1 == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numFour && sixthThrow1 == numFour)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow1 == numOne && sixthThrow1 == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 1: " << fivthThrow1 << "-" << sixthThrow1 << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numThree && sixthThrow == numThree)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numFive && sixthThrow == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numSix && sixthThrow == numSix)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numSix && sixthThrow == numFive)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 2 wins\n";
      }
      else if(fivthThrow == numOne && sixthThrow == numOne)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numTwo && sixthThrow == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numFour && sixthThrow == numFour)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
     else if(fivthThrow == numOne && sixthThrow == numTwo)
      {
        cout<< "Player 2: " << fivthThrow << "-" << sixthThrow << endl;
        cout << "Player 1 wins\n";
      }
      ////////////////////////////////
      
      else
      {
          cout<< "Tie! \n";
      }
}
```

Can someone kindly help me locate the issue? Thank you.

Comment: what is the meaning of "does not work" ?

Comment: Tactical note: When you have sequentially named or numbered variables you'll probably find the code a lot easier to write with an array.

Comment: Note that [there are better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14009637/10077) to generate random numbers in C++ than `rand()`.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the Debugger. With a debugger you can execute your program at your speed and watch what the program does as it does it. Typical usage is to step line by line until you see something you did not expect like the wrong value being stored or the wrong path being taken. The unexpected is a bug either in your program or your expectations. Either one needs to be fixed before you can continue.

Comment: Kind of pissed that the original Rand Considered Harmful presentation is no longer hosted. I'm sure someone posted a copy somewhere I have yet to find.

Comment: The meaning of does not work is that sometimes when I run the program, the results are not accurate. The results of the two thrown dices sometimes are messed up when printed, which makes the other player win, although he is not supposed to. In addition, I do not know why the player gets to not play individually but play with the second player at the same time.

Comment: Sometimes writing down the expected output alongside the actual output helps shake loose what the problem is. Recommendation: for now replace the `srand(time(0));` with `srand(0);` so you always get the same random numbers. Always getting the same numbers makes it a lot easier to reason about the output and spot where a change to the code actually did make a difference. When you get it working with 0, change the number to 1 and see if it still works. If it keeps working as you climb up to 5, consider putting `time(nullptr)` back in.

Comment: Note `nullptr` or `NULL`, not 0. You're supposed to be passing a pointer into the `time` function, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming that the random number generator did not work properly.

I can assure you that random generator is not your problem.

1. Write a function that chooses who goes first. Note - your code gives the players two chances, and even if they throw the same number - your code will keep going into a game.
2. Note that algorithm for checking winning and loosing combinations is the same for each player. Write it once, as a function, and call for the first player and then, if needed - for the second.
3. Don't pre-throw dice; get the value when needed. Could also be done in a separate, one-line function.
4. I am all for named constants, but your `numOne`..`numSix` is an overkill.
5. Wanted to comment on your variable names, but most of them are not needed anyway...
6. Tip: if you seed the random generator with a known value (like 0, 1, etc.), you will get the same pseudo-random sequence. Great for debugging.